# Remove some text from the "src" attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I would like to remove some text from the src attribute from an image using jQuery.

I need to use jQuery because I am using wordpress, and wordpress is automatically inserting that 150x150 into the img tag.

Here is my HTML:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blog_2-150x150.jpg">
```

I would like to use some jQuery to remove "-150x150" from the src. So it would look like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blog_2.jpg">
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `<img>` have an id or any other means of unique identification?

Comment: yeah to select it I will use `#rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2 img`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#img').attr('src',$('#img').attr('src').replace('-150x150', ''))
```

The id is '#img' in the example but you can change it for your case

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace the part you want to remove with an empty string and update the image's `src`:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2 img');
element.src = element.src.replace('-150x150', '');
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i tried this and it works. but i have multiple images with this issue and some reason this code only targets one of the images. do you know why and how to make it target all images with the selector `#rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2 img` ?

Comment: I was able to get it working by doing three instances of that code.

I used `(#rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2 li:nth-child(1) img`) in my selector and changed the nth child number for each instance.

is there a better way to do this?